# PHPVideoToolkit Execution error

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

When I try to convert a video to flv using [PHPVideoToolkit](https://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/) I get the following errors(output of the `getErrors()` method):

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "" was not found. Please check server write permissions and/or available codecs compiled with FFmpeg. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo().
    [1] => PHPVideoToolkit Error: Input file "/home/nik/video1.mp4" does not exist
)
```

`PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()` contains flv format.

I tested ffmpeg from command line and it works. I set permissions for both input and output directory and files to *777* but still getting the same errors.

What's wrong?

Comment: For what may be a temporary fix, see http://drupal.org/node/1476958#comment-5726580

Answer (score 0):

Well one part of this says that the file you are trying to input doesn't exist. Secondly, it appears the output filename is an empty string.